# Migrating django database from sqlite to postgres error with psycopg2

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-database, django-postgresql

I am trying to switch my django database from sqlite to postgres on my local machine. I am getting the following error when I try to run `python manage.py migrate`

```
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/splittapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Now I did make changes to the settings.py file in order to switch it from the sqlite3 database to the postgres database. My code looks like this.

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'splitt',
        'USER': 'splittadmin',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}`

This is is what the databse looks like insode of the postgres shell

`splitt      | splittadmin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |`

I was also looking up how to grand all rpivileges of a database to a superuser and I was getting mixed results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install psycopg2:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: do you know how I can now create a superuser within the new django - postgresql database so I can login to the admin site.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed psycopg2 in your virtual environment?

```
#in a terminal 
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: do you know how I can now create a superuser within the new django - postgresql database so I can login to the admin site.

Comment: You need to make a new post asking that. it sounds like a really common question, perhaps you’ll find an answer faster if you simply google it